# Identifying which MTA is running

Tags: linux, email-server

I dont have knowledge on linux and how can i know which mail server is running on my linux box? Postfix/Exim? Btw Didn't found postfix folder in etc/, where can i find master.cf? .Any idea for modify cPPOP?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For your second question, use locate to find master.cf

```
updatedb
locate master.cf
```

Answer (score 45):

Easiest way might be to get the PID of what's listening on port 25:

```
 # sudo lsof -i :25   
 COMMAND  PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE NODE NAME
 master  5664 root   12u  IPv4  13732       TCP *:smtp (LISTEN)
```

Then find out what that process is:

```
 # ps p 5664
 PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
 5664 ?        Ss     0:12 /usr/lib/postfix/master
```

And I'm running postfix. For sendmail, it looks like this:

```
 # lsof -i :25
 COMMAND   PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE NODE NAME
 sendmail 3445 root    4u  IPv4  12922       TCP localhost.localdomain:smtp (LISTEN)
```

**Edit**

Postfix config is under /etc/postfix ,
"sudo" might be necessary

Comment: `netstat -ltnp |grep :25` to get it all in one step.

Comment: Good one! Much faster.

Comment: Here is one more oneliner: lsof -n -i :25

Answer (score 14):

most mail servers will identify themselves

```
justin@bert ~ % telnet localhost 25
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 xxxx ESMTP Exim 4.69 Sat, 09 Jan 2010 15:08:05 -0500
```